# Sqlalchemy engine - run a function only after a database with tables has been created

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

On my FastApI application I am using sqlalchemy library:

```
from db import models
from db.database import engine

models.Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
...
```

If a db does not exist it creates one. Sometimes I delete that db and recreate, but I loose all the data. I run a function to repopulate db like this:

```
models.Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
initate_cities() #some code that puts different data to db from csv files
```

However, each time I reload the app the population function runs. I would Like that it runs when a database has been created. How could I achieve this?

Comment: have you tried to use Alembic? it helps you to update your database without having to delete it and create the tables again with sqlalchemy. With that you will just run the code one time and then delete the initate_cities() function and you will keep you data in the database. hope this answers your question.

Comment: @notrayen yes thats a good point, but I have a specific use case

Comment: You could try to query the db and if you don't get a result back, call the initiate_cities function

Comment: If you absolutely need to recreate the database every now and then (in general, Alembic is the way to go for database migrations), I would write the `initate_cities` function to be idempotent, i.e. only create each record if it doesn't exist. You could do it by querying the database first, or by having uniqueness constraints so that you can't put each record in more than once. This would also have the advantage that if you update your CSVs, you would add the new records to the database, keeping the old ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to repopulate the cities table when it is created.  It uses [`sqlalchemy.event`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.DDLEvents).  In this case we are listening for the `cities` table itself but you can also apply it to the entire `metadata` but you have to check if `tables` in `**kw` is non-empty to see if any tables were **actually** created.

#### Listening for `City.__table__`

```py
import sys

from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
    String,
    event
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base, aliased
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, or_, and_, delete, insert


username, password, db = sys.argv[1:4]


Base = declarative_base()

engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@/{db}", echo=True)


metadata = Base.metadata

class City(Base):
    __tablename__ = "cities"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)

def initiate_cities(connection):
    connection.execute(insert(City.__table__).values(name="Morro Bay"))
    connection.execute(insert(City.__table__).values(name="San Luis Obispo"))
    connection.execute(insert(City.__table__).values(name="Santa Margarita"))


@event.listens_for(City.__table__, 'after_create')
def receive_after_create(target, connection, **kw):
    initiate_cities(connection)



metadata.create_all(engine)

metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():
    assert session.query(City).count() == 3
```

#### Listening for `Base.metadata`

```py
@event.listens_for(Base.metadata, 'after_create')
def receive_after_create(target, connection, **kw):
    # Make you want to see if table name is in this list or maybe just having
    # a nonempty list is enough?
    if kw.get('tables', None):
        initiate_cities(connection)
```

#### Event handler code in this case is inside a transaction

When I tested this on postgresql the connection is in a transaction that includes the DDL changes, ie. `CREATE TABLE ...` .  So it will all be commited at once.  Which is pretty cool.  Ie. the table creation and data insertion.  This is the output of `echo=True`:

```
2022-12-24 13:26:40,619 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2022-12-24 13:26:40,619 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select relname from pg_class c join pg_namespace n on n.oid=c.relnamespace where pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid) and relname=%(name)s
2022-12-24 13:26:40,619 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00018s] {'name': 'cities'}
2022-12-24 13:26:40,622 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine 
CREATE TABLE cities (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


2022-12-24 13:26:40,622 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00013s] {}
2022-12-24 13:26:40,701 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO cities (name) VALUES (%(name)s) RETURNING cities.id
2022-12-24 13:26:40,702 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00031s] {'name': 'Morro Bay'}
2022-12-24 13:26:40,703 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO cities (name) VALUES (%(name)s) RETURNING cities.id
2022-12-24 13:26:40,703 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.001973s ago] {'name': 'San Luis Obispo'}
2022-12-24 13:26:40,704 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO cities (name) VALUES (%(name)s) RETURNING cities.id
2022-12-24 13:26:40,704 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.00313s ago] {'name': 'Santa Margarita'}
2022-12-24 13:26:40,705 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
```

Comment: Just to clarify when `metadata.create_all(engine)` is called the **second time** with `checkfirst=True`, the default, the event triggers but since all the tables already exist none will be created and therefore `kw['tables'] == []`.  The event specific to only the table doesn't get called twice.